# What is the best alternative to `SELECT ..., (SELECT ... FROM ...) FROM (SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM ...))` types of constructs?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote this query. But, I am wondering if there is any better/professional way to rewrite this.

> Find the employees who would receive bonuses in the current year. The condition for receiving bonus is, he would have to sell a specific category of product of the amount of at least $4000.

```
select yy.CurrentMonth, yy.ID, yy.Name, sum(yy.commission) as comm_total, sum(yy.bonus) as bonus_total
from
(select sysdate as CurrentMonth, ee.ID, ee.Name, cc.commission, (cc.commission * 25 / 100) as bonus
from employee ee,
(select e.id, pc.category_name, sum(quantity) as qty, pc.commission_rate, sum(quantity*pc.commission_rate) as commission
from sales s, product p, product_category pc, employee e
where to_char(sales_date, 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')
and s.employee_id = e.id
and s.product_id = p.id
and p.product_category_name = pc.category_name
group by pc.category_name, e.id, pc.commission_rate
order by e.id) cc
where ee.ID = cc.id
and cc.commission >=4000
) yy
group by yy.ID, yy.Name, yy.CurrentMonth
```

Edit: Table schema:

```
  CREATE TABLE "XYZ"."EMPLOYEE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "AREA_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
    "EMP_TYPE_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   );
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table PRODUCT
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "XYZ"."PRODUCT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table SALES
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "XYZ"."SALES" 
   (    "RECEIPT_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
    "SALES_DATE" DATE, 
    "QUANTITY" NUMBER, 
    "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER
   );
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table PRODUCT_CATEGORY
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "XYZ"."PRODUCT_CATEGORY" 
   (    "CATEGORY_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "COMMISSION_RATE" FLOAT(126)
   )  ;
```

Comment: 1. Write columns in the same order in select list as in group by.

Comment: 2. Use modern explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: 4. Avoid too long lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multi step cte, use indenation, use `JOIN` syntax, avoid long lines, capitalize keywords, avoid ordering in subquery and so on:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT e.id
        ,pc.category_name
        ,pc.commission_rate
        ,SUM(quantity)                      AS qty
        ,SUM(quantity * pc.commission_rate) AS commission
  FROM sales s
  JOIN product p
    ON s.product_id = p.id
  JOIN product_category pc
    ON p.product_category_name = pc.category_name
  JOIN employee e
    ON s.employee_id = e.id
  WHERE TO_CHAR(sales_date, 'yyyy') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')
  GROUP BY e.id, pc.category_name, pc.commission_rate
), cte2 AS 
(
  SELECT SYSDATE AS CurrentMonth
        ,ee.ID
        ,ee.Name
        ,cc.commission
        ,(cc.commission * 25 / 100) AS bonus
  FROM cte cc
  JOIN employee ee
    ON ee.ID = cc.id
  WHERE cc.commission >= 4000
)
SELECT CurrentMonth
      ,ID
      ,Name
      ,SUM(commission) AS comm_total
      ,SUM(bonus)      AS bonus_total
FROM cte2 
GROUP BY CurrentMonth, ID, Name;
```

Comment: Very nice, personally I hate constructs like this `SELECT ..., (SELECT ... FROM ...) FROM (SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM ...))`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit You can get benefits from scalar subquery caching, though, so disliking scalar subqueries (eg. `select ... (select colx from ...) ... from ...` as a general rule is perhaps not such a good thing...

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, What is the best alternative to `SELECT ..., (SELECT ... FROM ...) FROM (SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM ...))` types of constructs?

Comment: @anonymous, the query in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you don't need the extra join to the employee table - you're just wanting to exclude the rows where the summed commission is < 4000, right? If so, you can easily do that in the group by query by using the `having` clause, e.g.:

```
with sum_categories as (select   e.id,
                                 e.name,
                                 pc.category_name,
                                 sum(s.quantity) as qty,
                                 pc.commission_rate,
                                 sum(s.quantity * pc.commission_rate) as commission
                        from     sales s
                                 inner join product p on (s.product_id = p.id)
                                 inner join product_category pc on (p.product_category_name = pc.category_name)
                                 inner join employee e on (s.employee_id = e.id)
                        where    trunc(sales_date, 'yyyy') = trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')
                        group by pc.category_name,
                                 e.id,
                                 e.name,
                                 pc.commission_rate
                        having   sum (quantity * pc.commission_rate) >= 4000)
select   sysdate currentmonth, -- should this be trunc(sysdate, 'mm')?
         yy.id,
         yy.name,
         sum (yy.commission) as comm_total,
         sum (yy.commission * 25 / 100) as bonus_total
from     sum_categories yy
group by yy.id,
         yy.name;
```

You'll note that I changed your `to_char(sales_date, 'yyyy') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')` into `trunc(sales_date, 'yyyy') = trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')` because I prefer to keep the comparisons between the correct datatypes (you're comparing two dates, so I like to keep them as dates).

Comment: What is the best alternative to `SELECT ..., (SELECT ... FROM ...) FROM (SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM ...))` types of constructs?

Comment: The answer is... it depends. Making your query readable counts for a lot when you have to maintain or debug the sql statement. Doing things like using subquery factoring (aka the with clause) can help make things readable. Other things like changing scalar subqueries into joins (and vice versa) may have impacts on performance. However it depends entirely on your data and table structures as to which would perform best.